# Wait for cmdlet termination before exit script

Tags: powershell, scripting, remote-access

I am using the `Enter-PSSession` cmdlet inside a script to get a remote console in a remote computer. The script is executed from command line (CMD or windows "Run" dialog, not from PowerShell).

Works fine, but when interpreter terminates the script processing it returns to CMD/Windows, and the session is forcibly terminated.

I try to use the `Start-Job`/`Wait-Job` commands to hold the script execution until the remote session is terminated by an `exit`, but no success.

Is there any way to hold the script in the `Enter-PSSession` command while the remote console is running?

Comment: if you execute ps1 file from cmd you can use noexit switch. Like "powershell -noexit -f myscript.ps1" . You may also try to us Invoke-Command instead of EnterPSSession (if you just need to execute smth on remote machine)

Comment: Thanx Mike... but the -noexit Powershell.exe command line switch leaves you in the powershell console when the script terminates... and I do not want that...

Comment: I also the use the invoke-command for other purposes... but here I want the remote console to be interactive... and when the users dismisses the console (usually typing exit)... the script who invoked the remote-console terminates... and the system returns control to CMD or to Windows... (no powershell stay-open-windows are wanted!!! ;-) ;) ;) )

Comment: what if you type "exit" at the end of your script (and using no exit)

Comment: It's unclear what you want to happen when the remote session is being terminated by the user - what, specifically, do you want control returned to / to stay open? Please update you question directly.

Comment: Why are you using `Enter-PSSession` in the first place? The cmdlet is intended for interactive use, not for scripting. Try `Invoke-Command` instead.